# AttributeError: stem.lower 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python

```
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
stemmer = PorterStemmer()
class StemmedTfidfVectorizer(TfidfVectorizer):
   def build_analyzer(self):
      analyzer = super(TfidfVectorizer, self).build_analyzer()
      return lambda doc: stemmer.stem(analyzer(doc))
```

When I run the above lines of code, I get the following error.

> return lambda doc: stemmer.stem(analyzer(doc))
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/stem/porter.py", line   654, in stem
>
> stem = word.lower()
>
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'

How can this error be solved?

Comment: error is not in the code that you've given , its in line 654...please add that also

Comment: try to print the stack error with `traceback.print_exe..`

Comment: Why don't just just pass `stemmer.stem` to `preprocessor` in the constructor?

Answer (score 3):

You are passing a list object in `stemmer.stem()` .The method takes a string object as input.

From the **[DOCS](http://www.nltk.org/howto/stem.html)**:

```
from nltk.stem.porter import *
stemmer = PorterStemmer()
plurals = ['caresses', 'flies', 'dies', 'mules', 'denied']
singles = [stemmer.stem(plural) for plural in plurals]  # ---> loop through the list and process each element.
```